How to access the application that's exposed by kubectl
I'm learning k8s and following this tutorial: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/
My PC: Macbook Pro M2
Summary steps:

Start K8S cluster


minikube start


Create a deployment


kubectl create deployment kubernetes-bootcamp --image=gcr.io/google-samples/kubernetes-bootcamp:v1


Expose deployment as a service


kubectl expose deployment/kubernetes-bootcamp --type="NodePort" --port 8080


Access the application


kubectl get nodes -o wide // Get node ip INTERNAL-IP : 192.168.49.2 , EXTERNAL-IP : none


kubectl get services kubernetes-bootcam // Get service port : 8080:31677/TCP


curl http://192.168.49.2:31677 // NO response

I don't know why I can't access to the service by this way.
I tried to expose service by kubectl port-forward deployments/kubernetes-bootcamp 8080:8080 or use minikube minikube service kubernetes-bootcamp, the both ways is worked.

you might be missing a load balancer or try  http://127.0.0.1:31677/
"https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/handbook/accessing/#loadbalancer-access

I just studied at type NodePort, not LoadBalancer. So I want to resolve the issue with NodePort before continue with LoadBalancer
